# Showing Author Information and Latest Post by author in lightbox when clicked on the name of the author

Tags: jquery, ajax, author-template

I am showing  `details of all the authors including the avator, Name, Description in my blog`. When I click on the `OPTIONS TO CONNECT` link  a `lightbox` will open and I need to `show those details(which I mentioned above) inside the lightbox including the title of the latest post by the author`. Is there any way to do that? The following is the code that I use to display all the authors list.

```
<div id="bloggers">
<ul id="foo2">
<?php
    $authors = get_users('role=author&orderby=post_count&order=DESC');
    foreach($authors as $author) {
        echo "<li id=\"blogger_main\" style=\"float:left\">";
        echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
        echo $author->ID;
        echo "\" id=\"bloggers_image\">";
        echo get_avatar($author->ID);
        echo "</a>";
        echo '<div>';
        echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
        echo $author->ID;
        echo "\" id=\"blogger_name\">";
        echo the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id=\"auth_desc\">";
        echo the_author_meta('description', $author->ID);
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id=\"options_to_connect\">";
        echo "<a class=\"lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement\" href=\"#\">";
        echo "Options To Connect";
        echo "</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</li>";
    }?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I have tried the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
 jQuery('#options_to_connect a').on('click',function(event){         
event.preventDefault();
var author_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr('class'); 
jQuery.ajax({  
type: "POST",                  
url:  'http://www.myblog.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
   data: 'action=ajaxified_function&post_id='+author_id,    
   success: function (msg) {                                        
  jQuery('#cboxLoadedContent').html(msg);
},
error: function () {                  
  alert('Error');               
}  
});           
});       
});
```

and this in the functions.php

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
 function ajaxified_function() 
{ 
    $author = get_the_author_meta($_POST['author_id']);
    $auth_name = the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
    $avatar= get_avatar($author->ID);
    $desc = the_author_meta('description', $author->ID);
    echo '<div id="bloggers_title">'.$auth_name.'</div>
            <div id="bloggers_avatar">'.$avatar.'</div>
            <div id="bloggers_desc">'.$desc.'</div>';
  die();

}
```

But this displays just an image which is not clearly seen
Please tell me where I have done wrong.
Hope I am clear with my question. Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:**

I use the following script to register the js Dont know why it is not applying. Eventhough it gets registered the code is not working...

```
wp_register_script('lightbox',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox.js',
                       array(   'jquery', 'wp-ajax-response' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox');
wp_localize_script( 'lightbox', 'ajaxurl', 
                array( 
                    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                )
        );
```

It was working fine In the morning..But after sometime dont know why it got crashed and didnt work aferwards..

this is what shows in console

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpAjax = {"noPerm":"You do not have permission to do that.","broken":"An unidentified error has occurred."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Someone please help me

Comment: Are you asking how to make a lightbox? How to open it on click? Or how to display the latest author's post?

Comment: Please add your lightbox code to the question.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva. I have the lightbox for which I use a plugin called `Lightbox plus colorbox`. I need to display the contents that I said in the lightbox according to the name which is clicked. That is what I want

Comment: @toscho. I use a plugin called `Lightbox plus colorbox` to show the light box. Just one lightbox for all author names . not differnt lightbox for different author names which you can do with that plugin

Comment: Then explain what exactly doesn't work and what you have tried. Avoid the impression of a _do my work for me_ question.

Comment: I know i need to do it with ajax. But I dont know how. That is the problem. I dont want you to do my work. I need something to start with. Like how to implement ajax in a lightbox in wordpress kind of thing

Comment: Whatever I try is going the wrong way...

Comment: I have updated the question..please check it out @toscho

Comment: I updated my answer with working code that I tested for your specific needs. I really just filled the blanks I had left for you in my older answer with your code.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva  I have a small problem also. I need to add the title of the latest post by the author along with the other things. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Sunyatasattva Please Check this Question....http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95004/show-the-title-of-the-latest-post-by-author

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to implement that using AJAX. Read these two articles from the Codex for further information about integrating Wordpress with some AJAX action:

- [AJAX](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)
- [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Just to give you a head start, you will want something like this:

### Client-side (Javascript)

```
$(element).click(function() { 

    var data = {
        action:    'get_author_info',
        author_id:  your-author-id
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        var res = wpAjax.parseAjaxResponse(response, 'ajax-response');

            $.each( res.responses, function() { 
                if (this.what == 'has') {                                
                    $(your-lightbox).html( this.data );    
                } else {
                    // Some error/no result handling
                }
            });

    });
```

You will bind a click handler to your author element, pass some data: it is absolutely necessary that you pass the `action` part of the data. Anything else is up to you, perhaps you will want to pass an author id taking it through some [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for example.

Then you post to `ajaxurl`.

**Note** If you are using this script on the admin side, since WP 2.8 `ajaxurl` is always defined, if not, you have to define it. In any case, you should always parse AJAX requests through `admin-ajax.php`.

After getting your response, parse it and populate your lightbox HTML with the data you processed server-side.

### Server-side

In your plugin or `functions.php`:

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_author_info', 'my_get_author_info');
 add_action('wp_ajax_get_author_info', 'my_get_author_info');

function my_get_author_info(){
    $response = new WP_Ajax_Response();

        // Insert here everything you want to do to retrieve your
        // authors data, perhaps even process already the HTML
        // in some sort of template, using output buffer, or string
        // concatenation, or whatever.
        //
        // Then you will store it into a variable that we will call
        // $output, for convenience.

        $success_response->add(array(
        'what' => 'has',
        'data' => $output
    ));
    }
    $success_response->send();      
  }
```

Use [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to bind your `callback` function to `wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv` (basically the difference is that one works only if you are logged on, the other when you are not).

**Note** Bind the action name you defined in your AJAX data!

Define a `callback` function and, using [WP_Ajax_Response](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Ajax_Response) you can send back to your AJAX request all the data you need.

---

Basically this is all you need to get it working. Perhaps you might want to implement some `nonce`s, or [`check_ajax_referer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) but you will have to do a bit more reasearch at this point.

### Update

---

I took a look at your function, and, out of the box, I can see a few things that smell like might cause the error. For example, in your AJAX request you POST `post_id` and then in your functions you check for `$_POST['author_id']`.

Also, in your functions you use `the_author_meta` (which echoes the result) instead of `get_the_author_meta` (which `returns` it) to fill up variables.

Instead of checking all the mistakes in those functions I have rewritten them using the advices I gave you in my original answer, and it works perfectly. Let me explain:

#### Javascript

```
$('#options_to_connect a').on('click', function (e){         

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        action:    'ajaxified_function',
        author_id:  1
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        var res = wpAjax.parseAjaxResponse(response, 'ajax-response');

        $.each( res.responses, function() { 
            if (this.what == 'has') {                                
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').html( this.data );    
            } else {
                console.error('Error'); 
            }
            });
    });
});
```

Nothing too fancy here, but a bit cleaner code than the one you used. I put the `data` in a nice and tidy object, I also use the `ajaxurl` variable instead of hardcoding the URL. As I said before, if you use your script on admin side, you will already have `ajaxurl` available, if not, define it via [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) using `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`.

Then use `WPAjax` to parse the response. Be careful that in order to use that you have to enqueue `wp-ajax-response` in your `functions.php`.

#### PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
function ajaxified_function() 
{ 
    $response = new WP_Ajax_Response();

    $id        = $_POST['author_id'];
    $auth_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $id);
    $avatar    = get_avatar($id);
    $desc      = get_the_author_meta('description', $id);

    $output = "<div id='bloggers_title'>$auth_name</div>\n
               <div id='bloggers_avatar'>$avatar</div>\n
               <div id='bloggers_desc'>$desc</div>";


    $response->add(array(
        'what' => 'has',
        'data' => $output
    )); 

    $response->send();   

}
```

Here as well nothing fancy or different from what I said in my older answer, just adapted to your case. Using [WP_Ajax_Response](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Ajax_Response) dealing with this is a piece of cake.

Remember to use the `get_` versions of your functions! So that you have returned the data that you need.

Also, the `send()` method `die()`s so you don't have to do anything else to ensure a proper AJAX response.

Comment: Please check the updated Question...!!!! Please tell me where I have done wrong...

Comment: Updated answer with working code that I tested for your specific needs. I really just filled the blanks I had left for you in my older answer with your code.

Comment: I am getting an error that `wpAjax is not defined`.What can I do for that?

Comment: It is in my answer: **Be careful that in order to use that you have to enqueue `wp-ajax-response` in your functions.php.**

Comment: Let me try how to do...

Comment: I have a small problem also. I need to add the title of the latest post by the author along with the other things. Can you help me with that? @Sunyatasattva

Comment: Yes, I can help you, but this goes beyond the scope of this question. Questions on SE are supposed to be helpful to the future visitors as well, so keep things tidy and open a new question.

Comment: Ok..i will ask as another question

Comment: Please Check this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95004/show-the-title-of-the-latest-post-by-author

Comment: Hi.. I have a small problem in the ajax question. Can you please help me. Till today morning it was working. But after that wen I saw suddenly it was not working. I think it is where I register the js and using the `WP_localize_script`. Can you please help me with that? I have updated the question with how I used the wp_localize_script.

Comment: Plese check this out... This is what I see in console. I dont get it.. plese help... `<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var wpAjax = {"noPerm":"You do not have permission to do that.","broken":"An unidentified error has occurred."};
/* ]]> */
</script>`