# WP_Query by MAX post_id?

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to get the latest inserted post_id by an author using wp_query class. I have to use MAX(wp_posts.ID) in the args of the query i use. Is this somehow possible using wp_query class or do i have to use wpdb::get_results()? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think this link will be helpful to you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95004/show-the-title-of-the-latest-post-by-author

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i need to use MAX(wp_posts.ID) . I can not use orderby date.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$new=new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=> 1,'order_by'=>'DESC'));
$max_id;
if($new->have_posts()){
while($new->have_posts())
{
     $new->the_post();
     $max_id=the_id();

}
  }
echo $max_id;
```